# Apply element with absolute position for the top parent within scrollable content

Tags: html, css

I have a slider, which has fixed width. Then, there is a wrapper with rows and items, which has theoretically unlimited width. So you can use horizontal scroll bar to see all the things. Now, rows have also a special element called fixed. This element should remain on the same place whenever you scroll. My problem is that element is moving with other items.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.slider .wrapper {
  width: 5000px;
}
.slider .wrapper .item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.slider .wrapper .item.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.slider .wrapper .item.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.slider .wrapper .item.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.slider .wrapper .fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="fixed"></div>
            <div class="item red"></div>
            <div class="item blue"></div>
            <div class="item green"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note few thing, please:

- Element `.fixed` **must** be inside the element `.row` (the real code is too big to post, this is simple example to get the point)
- Just pure HTML/CSS, no JavaScript or jQuery
- There is a content before `.slider`, so using `position: fixed;` will destroy it, like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try using  `position:fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

Comment: @ManishPatel see edit with last note.

Comment: _“Element .fixed **must** be inside the element .row”_ - well, then your only other option than position:fixed (which takes the viewport as reference, so you would need to adapt the top value via script dynamically & constantly) would be to “move” the fixed element in the opposite direction of the scroll, also constantly updating it … My opinion: If you want any solution to this that is not a total performance killer and needs a lot of additional scripting - then you _need_ to change the HTML structure.

Comment: I know and that's the thing I wanted to avoid, but I wanted to try if it would be somehow possible.

Comment: Presumably there is going to be JavaScript involved in the slider functionality anyway - so if only the _initial_ HTML structure has to stay as it is, then you could take those .fixed elements out of the slides and put them into a different place in the DOM _via script_ as well, before you initialize the main slider functionality.

Comment: If element(s) `.fixed` should be outside of `.row`, let's say right after `.wrapper`, then their parent is now `.slider`, which has relative position. Well, I could live with that even it is not what I really wanted. But it looks like it is still not working good, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/be2wa8mt/

Comment: I think I found a workaround, when putting `.slider` within new parent, let's say `.sliders`, then elements `.fixed` needs to be after element `.slider`, then it workd good. I wanted them inside a `.row`, since it is the loop which prints them and there can be a lot of elements (I don't wanted to use one loop twice). Well, the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/be2wa8mt/1/